# Not able to run React-native app on android

Tags: node.js, react-native

I have everything installed,but when i use "npm-start" or "react-native run-android",it gets stuck at Loading "Dependency Graph ,done",nothing happens after that,any inputs would be helpful,running on Windows 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have a device connected (either emulator or physical device) by running `adb devices`

I usually have two command line windows open. In one window I run `react-native start` and in the other I run `react-native run-android`.

Essentially, `react-native start` runs a packager for your app while `react-native run-android` will install the app on the device. If you only run `react-native run-android`, a new packager should start in a new cmd window.

The packager (`react-native start`) is where you will see `Loading dependency graph... Done`.

Comment: i have a device connected,but still it gets stuck at Loading Dependancy..done,after that nothing happens

Comment: By running `react-native run-android`, a second cmd window should open. In the new window, you will see `Loading dependency graph... Done`. In the window which you ran `react-native run-android`, it should start installing the app onto the device. What is happening in the window which you ran `react-native run-android`?